# Что означает оператор & при перегрузке операторов? C++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Столкнулся с такой записью:

```
class PhoneNumber
{friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const PhoneNumber &);
friend istream & operator >> (istream &, PhoneNumber &);
```

И абсолютно не понимаю, что означает & здесь и зачем он нужен. По моим представлениям & - это оператор, возвращающий адрес операнды справа. То есть &peremennaya вернет адрес переменной. А тут?

Answer (score 2):

`&` тут относится к типу, возвращаемому из функции - это говорит от том, что функция возвращает ссылку на `ostream` или `istream` соответственно.

Да, у `&` много смыслов, но все они однозначны.

- `&` как оператор.

Может быть унарным или бинарным:

-- В унарном случае он таки да, вернет указатель на операнд, к которому его применили.

-- В бинарном случае - вернет результат побитового `И` операндов.

- `&` при объявлении типов. Превращает то что слева в ссылку.
- `&` как часть логического оператора `&&`. `&&` - особенный оператор, он не только делает свою работу, но и являлся (до C++11, см комментарий) *точкой следования*, и более того, если левый операнд - `false`, вычисление выражения справа гарантированно производиться не будет, а будет сразу выдано `false` в качестве результата. (Всегда сначала вычисляется то что слева, а потом, если слева - `true`, вычисляется то что справа.)

Comment: В C++11 точки следования [уничтожили](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Comment: А в аргументах? Вот PhoneNumber & - это значит, что в аргументе ссылка на тип PhoneNumber? А нельзя писать как в функциях, через указатели? - *PhoneNumber ?

Comment: "А в аргументах" - это частные случаи перечисленного выше. Это или унарный оператор, если речь идет о вызове функции, или объявление типа, когда речь идет об объявлении функции.

Comment: Все равно не понимаю. << - это не унарный оператор. Тогда зачем &? Если мы объявляем тип PhoneNumber , то почему нельзя написать friend ostream operator << (ostream, const PhoneNumber);

Comment: Есть тип ifstream и есть ТОЖЕ ТИП ifstream&. Вы путаетесь из-за того, что в одном месте столкнулось сразу слишком много сущностей.

Comment: Вы имеете дело с объявлением оператора ostream& operator << (ostream& s, const int a). В этом объявлении & выступает только в одной роли - он помогает объявить тип "ссылка на ostream".

Comment: Хорошо, с ostream я понял. А что насчет PhoneNumber? Для чего нам нужна ссылка на него через &? Не будет ли правильнее передавать тогда указатель?

Comment: Передача указателя приведет к усложнению синтаксиса, более того, появляется дополнительное место для того, чтобы словить ошибку, передав нулевой указатель.

Comment: То есть & для PhoneNumber - это значит, что объект PhoneNumber передается не копированием, а по ссылке, но без указателя?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120853/discussion-between-gbg-and-csharplooser).